# Can I do conditional selection of USE statements using preprocessor directives which rely on data from a file interface/header file in Fortran?

Tags: fortran, fortran90, intel-fortran

I would like to `use` different libraries in my fortran code (I am using intel fortran compiler as well) depending on which version of MKL is available at compile time.  There is a file interface included with an install of MKL which defines preprocessor macros for version numbers and build date - `/opt/intel/mkl/include/mkl.fi`

I thought the flow would be as follows:

1. Get version number of MKL from file interface mentioned above
2. Use the version number to decide which library to `use` via preprocessor directives
3. execute `use` statement to compile with correct library

If I place any `use` statements after an `include` statement, however, the compilation aborts after throwing  `error #6278: This USE statement is not positioned correctly within the scoping unit.`

**Is there any way to achieve conditional selection of `use` statements using preprocessor directives which rely on information from a file interface or header file?**

I cannot see how it is possible, because any `use` statements have to be before the `include` statement which provides the data required to decide which `use` statement to execute.  I have included below a sample which demonstrates what I'm trying to do, but will not work·

```
module MKLVersion

!Test for definition and value up here
#ifdef INTEL_MKL_VERSION  

#if INTEL_MKL_VERSION >=  110200
    use LAPACK95, only : ggevx, geevx, sygvd

#elif INTEL_MKL_VERSION < 110200
    use MKL95_LAPACK, only : ggevx, geevx, sygvd

#endif
#endif

! but dont actually get the definition till we get here

include '/opt/intel/mkl/include/mkl.fi'  

end module MKLVersion
```

Comment: Moving the include earlier probably won't help you anyway (if you could): literal include happens at the compilation stage _after_ preprocessing.  Perhaps there is a preprocessor `#include` approach that would work?  Or passing a definition with a value to the preprocessor.

Comment: This question is also discussed at https://software.intel.com/en-us/forums/intel-fortran-compiler-for-linux-and-mac-os-x/topic/676247 Note that the positioning issue is not the INCLUDE itself but the statements such as INTERFACE that get pulled in from the INCLUDE.

Comment: That was actually me as well, Steve!  I posted on here when I left yesterday because I figure you are on US time and probably wouldn't answer for a while.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The short answer to this question is, ultimately, no - as Steve Lionel pointed out, the included file had INTERFACE statements, which cannot come before a USE statement.

However, I found a solution for my particular use case, which enables compilation of code with both old and new MKL versions.  According to this [intel article from 2009](https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/blas-and-lapack-fortran95-mod-files), there is a way to call libraries which will work with older version of MKL:

> Notes:
>        *  f95_precision.mod, mkl95_lapack.mod and mkl95_precision.mod files will be removed in one of the future releases. The current version supports two USE statements - so you can choose or "USE MKL95_LAPACK" or " USE LAPACK95 ". For the future compatibility we recommend using "USE LAPACK95" statement.

So `USE MKL95_LAPACK` can be replaced with `USE LAPACK95` without breaking everything, which is good.